# How to use relative imports?

Tags: python, python-3.x, relative-path

How can I read the `/billy/var/text.txt` into `b.py`

The directory structure is:

```
/billy/b.py
/billy/var/text.txt
/sally/s.py
```

`s.py`

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append('..')
from billy import b

print('s.py - ' + os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
```

`b.py`

```
import sys, os

print('b.py - ' + os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
ag = open(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]) + '//var//text.txt').read()
```

Comment: Note: 'imports' usually refer to modules imported with the `import` statement. See the duplicate on how to get the absolute path of the current script, and from there, a path to anything relative from that position.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I followed the link to the solution provided.   `dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)` returns `G:/tst/sally` ... `filename = os.path.join(dirname, 'relative/path/to/file/you/want')` cannot access **b.py** because **b.py** is `G:/tst/betty/b.py` ... one step back in the hierarchy.

Comment: So add in a `..` or another `os.path.dirname()` call.

Comment: `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))` would be `G:/tst`.

Comment: And, in `b.py`, `__file__` would be `G:/tst/billy/b.py`, so `os.path.dirname(__file__)` would be `G:/tst/billy`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I didn't think of using os.path.dirname() to step back in the hierarchy that way.